# .htaccess vBulletin (with VBSEO) and wordpress issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vbulletin

I have vBulletin installed at root with VBSEO installed also with this .htaccess at root:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404..php

# Comment the following line (add '#' at the beginning)
# to disable mod_rewrite functions.
# Please note: you still need to disable the hack in
# the vBSEO control panel to stop url rewrites.
RewriteEngine On


# DO 301 non www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Some servers require the Rewritebase directive to be
# enabled (remove '#' at the beginning to activate)
# Please note: when enabled, you must include the path
# to your root vB folder (i.e. RewriteBase /forums/)

#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(admincp/|modcp/|cron|vbseo_sitemap|api\.php)
RewriteRule ^((archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?))$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images)/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]

#SECFILTERENGINE OFF
#SECFILTERSCANPOST OFF
```

and wordpress installed in a subfolder /blog/

Wordpress works fine until I try to use permalink settings such as "Post name". Wordpress add a .htaccess file in /blog/ with the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Wordpress then no longer is accessible and Firefox detects that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Any advice on fixed this issue woulde be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/` to all vBulletin rules where it may be affected

Comment: I'm sorry I dont fully understand, nothing is effeted in vBulletin only in wordpress when I enable permalinks and so wordpress creates the above .htaccess file in the /blog/ folder

Comment: I mean add that `RewriteCond` to each `RewriteRule` in root `.htaccess` that has pattern like `(.*)` or `^(.+)$`. So URLs with `/blog/...` will not be affected by vBulletin rules.

Comment: That did not fix the issue unfortunately. When no permalinks are selected in wordpress the blog works (no .htaccess file created by wordpress) its only when permalinks are used and wordpress creates that .htaccess file I get this error.

Comment: I'd use the rewrite log to find an error. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging